# How to correctly Save & Load a Boolean variable in UE

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint, blueprint

How to correctly save a Boolean variable called Lighter, which is responsible for turning the Lighter light off and on, using Blueprint in Unreal Engine?

[Instance1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwNtb.png)

[Instance2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f07dy.png)

[Instance3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0jWv.png)

[Instance4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oMld.png)

[SaveGameBP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjOGg.png)

[L1 plyer Lighter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He57o.png)

I wanted to know how to correctly save Boolean variables.

Comment: What do you mean with "save"? As in "to disk"?